# hapi swagger deployment issue

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, hapi

I have a microservice in hapi where I have integrated hapi-swagger. Its working perfectly fine on localhost: http://localhost:5000/documentation however now that I have deployed it the server link gives blank page:
https://stage.com/v1/user/documentation

I know the issue, its basically that when i use it on localhost its fetching all these in background:
http://localhost:5000/swaggerui/swagger-ui.css

http://localhost:5000/swaggerui/swagger-ui-bundle.js

http://localhost:5000/swaggerui/swagger-ui-bundle.js

http://localhost:5000/swaggerui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js

http://localhost:5000/swaggerui/extend.js

http://localhost:5000/swaggerui/favicon-32x32.png

On the deployed version,
its fetching like this:

https://stage.com/swaggerui/swagger-ui.css

https://stage.com/swaggerui/swagger-ui-bundle.js

https://stage.com/swaggerui/swagger-ui-bundle.js

https://stage.com/swaggerui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js

https://stage.com/swaggerui/extend.js

https://stage.com/swaggerui/favicon-32x32.png

Now these urls dont exist hence i am getting 404 on them.
There are multiple microservices running under nginx reverse proxy.

I need help with giving these swaggerui files the right path. Where to do that? should that be done inside this one microservice or it has to be done in the proxy file. and if it has to be done in proxy file another thing to be considered there are other microservices where swagger might be integrated later so how would the proxy file changes impact that

in this one microservice i have basic conifguration which picks up all the routes info

```
 await server.register([
      Inert,
      Vision,
      {
        plugin: HapiSwagger,
        options: swagger_options,
      },
    ]);
```